# How do I make the text from \textblock streamlined by another text?

Tags: block

```
\subsection{Языковые средства C++}

\text{Ввод-вывод
В большинстве олимпиадных задач для ввода и вывода используются стандартные
потоки. В C++ стандартный поток ввода называется cin, а стандартный поток
вывода – cout. Входными данными для программы обычно являются числа и
строки, разделенные пробелами и знаками новой строки. Из потока cin они
читаются следующим образом:}\\
\begin{textblock*}{5cm}(3cm, 10.5cm)
{\large\textsf{
    \textcolor{blue}{int} a, b;\\
    \textcolor{gray}{string} x;\\
    cin >> a >> b >> x;
}}
\end{textblock*}
Такой код работает в предположении, что элементы потока разделены хотя бы
одним пробелом или знаком новой строки.
Поток cout используется для вывода:
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Or in other words: your posted code does not compile. Please try yourself.

Comment: Why are you using `textblock`? The `textpos` package is for placing text at exact locations on the page. For what you are doing you should just use a `minipage` for the displayed code. If by "streamline by another text" you mean something like having the text wrap around the code display, you can combine it with [wrapfigure](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Wrapping_text_around_figures).